# Is it possible to make this vessel sink into an undermount and function properly?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink, installation

I have a small bathroom I'm trying to remodel and have a subcontractor working with me. I kinda don't trust him any longer. I'd fire him but I'm in a contract and we're very close to the finish line. I've caught him in lies regarding what can or can't be done regarding some unconventional approaches to working with other projects in my home. For example, I had a modern vessel sink made of resin stone and asked if the edges could be cut off so we could make it into an undermount sink. He told me that the fabricator he works with said it can't be done. I suspected he was full of it and went to a quartz fabricator location myself. I just walked in unannounced, was able to speak to someone and asked if it could be done. They dropped what they were doing and did it for me in less than 25 minutes. This was the sink I had cut leaving a 1.5" lip around the ramp's edges which will serve as a way to anchor the sink underneath the quartz vanity top:

[image]

That turned out very well. I will try to provide photos of that sink at a later time. But I also have another bathroom that's much smaller and I'm having a hard time pulling it all together. Firstly, if I do a vessel sink, I'd have to get a very tall faucet that would stick above the bottom of the medicine cabinet on the wall. All medicine cabinets in our home have been installed 47" from the floor. Meaning, the bottom of the mirrored cabinet is 47" from the floor. Our cabinets with the quarts vanity top will be at a height of 36" from the floor, which is the newer standard, I believe.

I know there are a lot of options out there. My subcontractor said they can cut a circular hole to match the shape of an undermount sink (whether it be circular or square). I am heavily into modern design (which works against simple easy solutions, of course) and am trying to make my home aesthetically pleasing while working in my dimensions. Lastly, the room is very small and the depth from front to back for the vanity sink is only 20".

So, I have two questions. Below are two options for sinks I really want to work, with the first one being the preferred option. They're vessel sinks but I want to make either one I choose into an undermount sink. I have ideas on how to help support the sink inside the vanity in addition to it being epoxied in place. Since there is no lip to grab onto I would use 2x2 studs to create a frame to rest the sink on top of (inside the cabinet) so that the top edge of the sink is level with the top of the cabinetry before the quartz countertop is laid on top. My last question is, since this sink is 5" - will this be too low to allow for proper drainage of the water?

Not sure if it matters but this is going to be a powder room that will only get occasional use. It's not a main bathroom. Lastly, the dimensions for the vanity area are 20"Dx37.5"W. This sink is 24.5" wide by just under 15" deep (front to back):
[image]
Link with specifications can be found here:
https://www.homary.com/item/vessel-oval-bathroom-wash-sink-stone-resin-26862.html

A possible second option is to go with this sink. But since it's 16" in diameter (I know I'm already pushing it with the option above at 15") I don't think there would be adequate clearance for a faucet centered behind the sink:
[image]
Link with specifications can be found here: [https://www.amazon.com/VIGO-VG04016-StoneTM-Vessel-Bathroom/dp/B07NP29NHG/ref=sr_1_4?crid=3MOMIQOM6B30P&keywords=Scarabeo%2B8811%2BBucket%2BCeramic%2BCircular%2BVessel&qid=1664024673&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIwLjIwIiwicXNhIjoiMC4wMCIsInFzcCI6IjAuMDAifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=scarabeo%2B8811%2Bbucket%2Bceramic%2Bcircular%2Bvessel%2Caps%2C206&sr=8-4&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.18ed3cb5-28d5-4975-8bc7-93deae8f9840&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NP29NHG)

May I get some solid input, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Too many questions, too much extraneous information.   You should edit this question down to one clear question with material that makes it easy to answer.  I suggest removing the entire story about your previous experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason why any basin could not be mounted in any manner.  I've seen all kinds of artistic dishes and bowls adapted to be sinks by drilling a two inch hole in the bottom, and I've seen them mounted any way you want.

For the three basins you have pictured in the question there is no lip to the top edge so no way to use brackets to fasten them to the underside of the counter.   *Maybe* you could just glue them directly to the counter but I've never seen that done professionally and I don't think I'd pioneer that technique myself.   You should build a cradle, or stand, that would support them from the bottom with legs on the floor of the cabinet.  Then you would just silicone the top of the basin to the counter to provide a seal and some stability but not to entirely support the weight.

Make sure the position of the drain pipe coming horizontally from the wall is low enough to accommodate your choice of basin after undermounting.